# Clarifying analyticity in complex functions and domain ranges

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I'm confused about the concept of analyticity in complex functions. How can I determine the domain of analyticity for a function?

For example:
1.

> $$ {f_1}({\zeta _1}) = \frac{{\zeta _1^2 + m}}{{1 - m\zeta _1^2}},\quad \left| {{\zeta _1}} \right| \le 1 $$
>
> Since $(0 \le m \le 1)$, $f_1$ is an analytic function within the unit
> circle.
>
> $$ g_1(\zeta_1) = -\zeta_1 - 2\zeta_1^2 - 3\zeta_1^3 \cdots, \quad |\zeta_1| \le 1 $$
>
> $g_1(\zeta_1)$ is an analytic function within the unit circle as well.
>
> $$ f_1(\zeta_1) \cdot g_1(\zeta_1) $$ This function is also analytic
> within the unit circle.

2:

> $$ f_0(\zeta_0) = \frac{1 + m\zeta_0^2}{\zeta_0^2 - m}, \quad |\zeta_0| \ge 1 $$
>
> Due to $(0 \le m \le 1)$, $f_0$ is an analytic function outside the
> unit circle, including the point at infinity. $$ g_0(\zeta_0) =
> -\frac{1}{\zeta_0} - 2\frac{1}{\zeta_0^2} - 3\frac{1}{\zeta_0^3} \cdots $$
> $g_0(\zeta_0)$ is an analytic function outside the unit
> circle, including the point at infinity as well.

Where a function is analytic, does it represent the domain of definition? Why does it relate to $m$?

This question has been bothering me for a while. I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "does it represent the domain range?".

A rational function such as $f_1$ is analytic everywhere in $\mathbb C$ except at the zeros of its denominator.  In this case the zeros are $\zeta_1 = \pm 1/\sqrt{m}$; since $0 \le m \le 1$, those zeros have absolute value $\ge 1$, i.e. they are not inside the unit circle, so $f_1$ is analytic inside the unit circle. Not **just** inside the unit circle, but apparently here we are only interested
in the region inside the unit circle.

The sum of a power series such as $g_1$ is analytic inside its circle of convergence.  In this case the radius of convergence is $1$, so $g_1$ is analytic inside the unit circle.  BTW, $|\zeta_1| \le 1$ is incorrect here, it should be $|\zeta_1| < 1$:  this series diverges when $|\zeta_1| = 1$.

The product of two functions is analytic in a region where both of the functions are analytic.